# Accessing Datatable not visbile Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to select multiple checkboxes from JS Datatable and submit them, then reseting them on a reset button click.

I already checked and tried the solution found in here and it just gets the not hidden elements : [DataTable Checkboxes not getting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059470/datatable-checkboxes-not-getting-value)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
            responsive: true

        });

        $('form').on('reset', function(e){
            $('input[type="hidden"][name="deliver[]"').remove();
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').click();
            return false;
        });

        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            let form = $(this);

            // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
            table.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                 // Create a hidden element
                if(!$.contains(document, this)) {
                    form.append(
                        $('<input>')
                            .attr('type', 'hidden')
                            .attr('name', this.name)
                            .val(this.value)
                    );
                }
            });
                    return false;
        });

    });
```

The problems are like following :

- The submit only adds the current page checkboxes as hidden inputs, not all pages (the return false is there just for testing)
- The reset button uncheck only current page checkboxes
- The remove functions works as supposed
- The click is used instead of switching prop because of the template I'm using (css staff)

Comment: Please show your DataTables initialization code. If you use server-side processing mode, data from pages other than current may not be accessible unless you use custom programming or dedicated plug-in.

Comment: var table = $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
            responsive: true

        }); 

it is the first line

Comment: Try using `table.$()` instead of `$()` in your reset code. Also do you have `name` attribute assigned to your checkboxes?

Comment: Gyrocode this has nothing to do with the question. Thank you anyway, if the jquery deleted the first page elements, it means it work, not a syntax error neither a naming issue. This is a specific problem to Datatables JS.

Comment: I am the author of the answer you've mentioned in the question. `$()` works only for current page, that is why checkboxes from other pages are not reset. Your submit code seems to be OK. Are you able to create an example demonstrating the issue using [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqoh17v0/) as a template?

Comment: I'm going to create the jsFiddle, but the submit also is submitting only current page, while using your code there (table.$())

Comment: You are right @Gyrocode.com it was all about $() and I wasn't using your code exactly like it on the answer in the other thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be related to usage of table as $()

```
$('form').on('reset', function(e){
            var $form = $(this);

            // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
            table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
                if(!$.contains(document, this)){
                    // If checkbox is checked
                    if(this.checked){
                        // Create a hidden element
                        this.checked = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            var $form = $(this);

            // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
            table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
                if(!$.contains(document, this)){
                    // If checkbox is checked
                    if(this.checked){
                        // Create a hidden element
                        $form.append(
                            $('<input>')
                                .attr('type', 'hidden')
                                .attr('name', this.name)
                                .val(this.value)
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```